# Typescript - It is a good practice for the frontend to type the api return

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

for example: An api returns me in a given query the products, which happens to be an array of objects containing: `id, name, description`. Can I in the frontend create an interface to type this return? is this a good practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issues with having a custom typed object type in your code. This can be helpful in development also as you will get type hints from IDEs like VSCode etc.

I usually have all my custom types defined in a separate file and export it from there to different screen & components.

```
export type OptionType = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
};
```

You can also save a lot of debug time by properly defining these type and their internal mappings.